# libphonenumber for php

Tags: php, libphonenumber

I am using https://github.com/davideme/libphonenumber-for-PHP for formatting phonenumbers

I am having issue with 1800 numbers

```
$formatnumber = "1800123456"
$country = "AU";    

$phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil::getInstance();

try {
    $NumberProto = $phoneUtil->parse( $formatnumber , $country );
} catch ( NumberParseException $e ) {
    echo $e;
}

$formattedNumber =  $phoneUtil->format( $NumberProto, PhoneNumberFormat::NATIONAL );
```

What I am expecting to get back from `$formattedNumber` is `"1800 123456"`

What I get back is an unformatted number `"1800123456"`

If there something I need to do doing to get it to format correctly?

Answer (score 4):

It works for me with pretty much your code:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';


$formatnumber = "1800123456";
$country = "AU";

$phoneUtil = \libphonenumber\PhoneNumberUtil::getInstance();

try {
    $NumberProto = $phoneUtil->parse($formatnumber, $country);
} catch (NumberParseException $e) {
    echo $e;
}

$formattedNumber = $phoneUtil->format($NumberProto, \libphonenumber\PhoneNumberFormat::NATIONAL);

echo $formattedNumber;
```

Response:

```
1800 123 456
```

I am using my version of libphonenumber-for-php though: https://github.com/giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php