# How to use libphonenumber for php

Tags: php, libphonenumber

I was having difficulty getting libphonenumber for PHP to run as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125433/libphonenumber-for-php).
All I got was:

My output:

```
Warning: require(/var/www/phone/libphonenumber/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/phone/libphonenumber/index.php on line 2

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/phone/libphonenumber/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/php/PEAR:/var/www/cakephp/lib') in /var/www/phone/libphonenumber/index.php on line 2
```

What finally got it working was installing composer, and moving the generated composer.phar file into the libphonenumber folder, then running the install procedure.  This step is missing from the docs, so I wanted to list it here.  Thank you to  @Simon_eQ for assisting me with this.

Comment: It just seems like you're not using the correct path to the autoload.php file. Where is your current PhP file using include() ?

Comment: Can you show us your `require` code?

Comment: I hadn't moved the composer.phar file to the correct directory before running it. Problem solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

`php composer.phar dump-autoload`

This will generate autoload files if not already present.